# How to perform upsert in SalesForce Bulk API with Multiple Update Key?

Tags: api, bulk-api

I created some classes in Java, which integrate my existing system with SalesForce via Bulk API. The component runs smoothly when inserting new objects. I was wondering how it would be possible to upsert -OR- update new objects based on multiple keys (essentially a composite key), for instance: Id and DateCreated. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Upserts require the use of an external id field on the object. You could probably concatenate your composite key, assign that value to the external id in the Salesforce record, and then use that for upserting.